# How to scroll stacked containers with sticky header in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am trying to achieve scroll in Flutter Web where I have few containers which are stacked and I use SingleChildScrollView to scroll the widget. However, when I scroll the first container everything working fine but the second one which is a child of the second container responds to the scroll without completing the initial one. And also is there a way to make a sticky header for the second container. How can I make the 3rd container(orange) to scroll after the 2nd(blue) one is finished scrolling? Here is what I am trying to achieve:
https://yobithemes.com/demo/html/freda/dark-video-index.html

And here what I got so far:

[image]

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          IntroScreen(),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            color: Colors.orange,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it by using sliver.

`SliverToBoxAdapter` fill the transparent area with *screen height - app bar height*.

`SliverAppBar`: make it sticky by setting *floating* and *pin* to true

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          IntroScreen(),
          CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50,
                ),
              ),
              SliverAppBar(
                // toolbarHeight: 50,
                floating: true,
                pinned: true,
                title: Container(
                  child: Center(child: Text('Header')),
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) => Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-50,
                    color: Colors.primaries[index % Colors.primaries.length],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```